# client-server question

Tags: c#, multithreading

If i have a client that is connected to a server and if the server crashes, how can i determine, form my client, if the connection is off ? the idea is that if in my client's `while` i await to read a line from my server ( `String a = sr.ReadLine();` ) and while the client is waiting to recieve that line , the server crashes , how do i close that thread that contains my `while` ?

Many have told me that in that `while(alive) { .. }` I should just change the alive value to true , but if my program is currently awaiting for a line to read, it won't get to exit the while because it will be trapped at `sr.ReadLine()` .

I was thinking that if i can't send a line to the server i should just close the client thread with `.abort()` . Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a `TimeOut` parameter in `ReadLine` method which takes a `TimeSpan` value and times out after that interval if the response is not received..

```
public string ReadLine(TimeSpan timeout)
{
   // ..your logic.
)
```

For an example check these SO posts -

[Implementing a timeout on a function returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370811/implementing-a-timeout-on-a-function-returning-a-value)

[Implement C# Generic Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout)

Comment: do you have an example at hand of this ?

Comment: See the updated answer, I just found some SO posts providing nice examples of it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the server app your own, or something off the shelf?

If it's yours, send a "heart beat" every couple of seconds to let the clients know that the connection and service are still alive. (This is a bit more reliable than just seeing if the connection is closed since it may be possible for the connection to remain open while the server app is locked.)

Comment: Did you mean "heart beat"?  That's one of my boss's favorite buzz words/phase.

Answer (score 0):

If the server crashes I imagine you will have more problems than just fixing a while loop.  Your program may enter an unstable state for other reasons.  State should not be overlooked.  That being said, a nice "server timed out" message may suffice.  You could take it a step further and ping, then give a slightly more advanced message "server appears to be down".

Answer (score 0):

That the server crashes has nothing to do with your clients. There are several external factors that can make the connection go down: The client is one of them, internet/lan problems is another one.

It doesn't matter why something fails, the server should handle it anyway. Servers going down will make your users scream ;)

Regarding multi threading, I suggest that you look at the BeginXXX/EndXXX asynchronous methods. They give you much more power and a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid any strategy that relies on thread abort().  If you cannot avoid it, make sure you understand the idiom for that mechanism, which involves having a separate appdomain and catching ThreadAbortException