# Timeout for BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, timeout, backgroundworker

I am using `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` in my **WPF** application.

How can I set **timeout** for `BackgroundWorker` ?

Comment: something , it does something, and i want to stop do it after timeout.

Comment: Yeah as BugFinder said use cancellation token to cancel out of the execution

Comment: Actually it is very logically to integrate BackgroundWorker and Timer. Thats a good idea in fact!

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is following

**backgroundworker1** does the work - it accepts cancellation so you can make it stop.

**backgroundworker2** does a loop while the time out is pending, and on time out completes.

If **backgroundworker1** is still running, the `RunWorkerComplete` of this `BackgroundWorker`, kills off **backgroundworker1**..

This should also accept ***cancellation*** so that if **backgroundworker1** completes and this is still running, you can cancel it.

Comment: Probably but, to get a fairly accurate time out, as well as the functionality, there arent many options. You could do some form of descendant and constantly check for time passed in your original worker, but, if you had any form of blocking call it could well exceed the timeout.

Answer (score 4):

BackgroundWorker does not directly support a timeout, but it does support cancellation.  This will work well if the work being done is an a loop or other structure where you can periodically check the CancellationPending member to then abort.  You will need some thing else to tell the background worker to cancel after the timeout.  Here I used an async call of an action.

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var bg = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        bg.DoWork += LongRunningTask;

        const int Timeout = 500;
        Action a = () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep( Timeout );
                bg.CancelAsync();
            };
        a.BeginInvoke( delegate { }, null );

        bg.RunWorkerAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void LongRunningTask( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs eventArgs )
    {
        var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        foreach ( var i in Enumerable.Range( 0, 5000 ) )
        {
            if ( worker.CancellationPending )
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Keep working
            }
        }
    }
```

If this doesn't really fit what your are trying to accomplish you may be interested in the generic timeout solutions found at [Implementing a timeout on a function returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370811/implementing-a-timeout-on-a-function-returning-a-value) or [Implement C# Generic Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-sharp-generic-timeout).  You could use those inside the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Thank you but it not works , eventArgs.Cancel never comes true .

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan Oh, of course it does not, I was checking the wrong object for cancel information (^_^;).  I have edited with a fix.

Comment: Works Like a Charm. Many Thanks....  If you're going OO mode ;-) , Your can Global var bg = new BackgroundWorker and use CancelAsync(); anywhere in your code.