# java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

Why am I getting a "must be caught or declared to be thrown" error with this code ? All I want is to test a bunch of code by pasting it into a new java program what is the easiest way to bunch of code ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Selenium\\scrapjv\\interface\\NASDAQlist.txt"));
        List<String> symbolList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            symbolList.add(sc.nextLine());
        }

        PrintWriter logput = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\User\\Selenium\\scrapjv\\interface\\log.txt", "UTF-8");
        for (String symb : symbolList) {
            System.out.println(symb);
        }
        logput.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Search for error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22must+be+caught+or+declared+to+be+thrown%22) *before* asking. "Easiest" way is to add `throws Exception` to the main method definition; find a relevant [near-]duplicate for details. (Sadly almost every duplicate is itself a poor question with an equally poor title.)

Comment: Ahh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589302/why-is-throws-exception-necessary-when-calling-a-function seems better than most and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392446/when-to-use-throws-in-a-java-method-declaration?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the methods you're calling can throw `FileNotFoundException` if the file isn't found:

```
 public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException
 public PrintWriter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
```

Java's compiler checks that some thrown exceptions -- those other than RuntimeException and its subclasses -- are either caught or declared thrown. Compilation will fail otherwise. This helps find some errors at compile-time, before the program is ever run.

One option is to declare your calling function to throw the exception or a superclass:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

A better option in this case is to catch the exception and do something with it. For example, here's how you can do that for the Scanner() exception:

```
    File inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Selenium\\scrapjv\\interface\\NASDAQlist.txt");
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( inFile );
        List<String> symbolList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            symbolList.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file: " + inFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths

Comment: nice i'm new to java and didn't know this stuff thank's

Answer (score 1):

Your two `Scanner` declaration lines have a chance to throw an *exception*, which are basically errors that happen after the code is executed (because of this they are sometimes called runtime errors). Because the compiler knows that your code might make a `FileNotFoundException` happen, it requires you to `catch` the exception.

This is done by enclosing the code in a try-catch block.

```
try {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Selenium\\scrapjv\\interface\\NASDAQlist.txt"));
    List<String> symbolList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        symbolList.add(sc.nextLine());
    }


    PrintWriter logput = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\User\\Selenium\\scrapjv\\interface\\log.txt", "UTF-8");
    for (String symb : symbolList) {
        System.out.println(symb);
    }
    logput.close();


} catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths