# why don't we use throw new exception sometimes?

Tags: java, oop, servlets, web-applications

For example in this method : `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException,java.io.IOException {}`

throw new ServletException,java.io.IOException ; is not being used in the method definition . why is that ? can anyone please tell me why? I'm new to java .

in the below code throw is used and why is it not used in the above method which throws exception.

```
  class SomeClassName { 
        void show() throws Exception
           {
            throw new Exception();
            }
         }
```

Comment: throw and throws are two different things. Google them

Comment: It's not explicitly throwing `ServletException` but it calls other methods which does.

Comment: some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392446/when-to-use-throws-in-a-java-method-declaration

Comment: Same reason we write `public int getNumberOfCats() {` instead of `public return 1; getNumberOfCats() {`

Comment: My question is why throw is not used inside that throws method ?? . So what is the purpose of writing throws if it cant throw an exception?

Answer (score 2):

`throws Exception` and `throw new Exception();` do completely different things.

`throws Exception` is part of the method signature, and specifies that "this method is allowed to throw `Exception`s".

`throw new Exception();` is a statement that actually throws an exception.

This is not valid (since `throw` can't be part of a method signature):

```
public void test() throw new Exception(); {
}
```

and nor is this (since `throws Exception` isn't a statement):

```
public void test() {
    throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally, '**throws**' itself means that it shall be associated with a behavior. '**throw**' means that it shall be associated with an action.

Similarly, `throws` as a behavior is associated with a `method` signature.

```
public void test() throws CutomException{
    //do whatever
    throw new CustomException
}
```

The aforementioned `method` has a trait of throwing `CustomException` (`throws`), if triggered within `method` body to do the same (`throw`).

Answer (score 0):

`throw new Exception` "creates" an exception, whereas `throws Exception` simply "throws" any encountered exceptions to the caller method.