# Single Vs. Multiple For Loops In Python?

Tags: python

When comparing the following code samples in `python` (the `300` is just an example; in practicality, assume there are `10,000,000` items that we need to loop through):

```
sum = 0
for i in xrange(0, 300):
    sum += i
```

Vs.

```
sum = 0
for i in xrange(0, 100):
    sum += i
for i in xrange(100, 200):
    sum += i
for i in xrange(200, 300):
    sum += i
```

Are both versions the same in terms of running time? I have a problem where I have a huge vector (say, 10,000 items). I don't necessarily have to loop through all of it, unless some conditions are met (these conditions can only be assessed when the first loop -- which using the first 100 items -- is done).

Then, I should continue the looping only if some conditions are met (these conditions can only be assessed when the next 100 items are examined).

Then, I should continue the looping only if some conditions are met (these conditions can only be assessed when the next 100 items are examined).

Same story, until I reach the end of the vector................

Given the fact that I can solve my problem in a modular way, by examining points:

{0, 100}
{100, 200}
{200, 300}
........
{9900, 10,000}

All I am trying is to get a sense whether the second approach is as efficient as the first one. Thanks.

**note: the `sum` is used here for simplicity. In practice, the running time of the mathematical operations that will be used is significantly greater. That's why I am trying to find ways to optimize the running time by examining different coding approaches...**

Comment: By vector, do you mean `list`? Or really a vector, like from C++?

Comment: @Blender: it is a numpy array. yet, you can assume it is a `list` -- it does not really matter. What I am trying to get a sense is, what is the best coding approach in `python` to solve the problem I am facing. Thanks!

Comment: See my edit. Not sure if that's what you're doing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of improvement were you hoping to see?

[`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) will help you observe the difference:

```
$ python -m timeit 'sum = 0
> for i in xrange(0, 300):
>     sum += i'
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'sum = 0
> for i in xrange(0, 100):
>     sum += i
> for i in xrange(100, 200):
>     sum += i
> for i in xrange(200, 300):
>     sum += i'
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 usec per loop
```

Personally, I would go for:

```
$ python -m timeit 'sum(xrange(300))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.34 usec per loop
```

This example is perhaps not the best way to assess whether you'll be able to optimise your *actual* code, but it does demonstrate how you can test a small snippet for its running time.

Just remember [what Donald Knuth said about optimisation](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29) ;-)

Here's a way you could checkpoint your iteration and break out if required:

```
>>> for index, item in enumerate(vect):
...     results = do_stuff_with(item)
...     if index % 100 == 0 and should_we_stop(results):
...         break
```

What would be even better is if you could have `do_stuff_with()` return a `tuple` indicating whether it has finished, then you can check *every* iteration whether you're done, rather than wait:

```
>>> for item in vect:
...     finished, results = do_stuff_with(item)
...     if finished:
...         break
```

Just to reiterate (no pun intended) it's very hard to say how (or even *whether*) to optimise your actual code without actually seeing it!

Comment: Johnsyweb: I edited my post -- please take a look at it to see what I am trying to achieve. Assume that I have a `list` of say 10,000,000 items even. The key is the approach -- if it is sound, or alternatively, better ideas are out there. Thanks.

Comment: @user3262424: It is hard to say how (or even *whether*) to optimise your *actual* code without seeing it. If you can break your `list` (I *presume* you meant `list`, not `vector`) into `slice`s, and assess at checkpoints whether you continue or break your flow of execution, then you should structure your code accordingly. I've demonstrated how you can time and compare different approaches. That's all I can do with what you have given me.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I can break my `list` to slices, but don't want to do it as it created copies of the same list. this will take time. instead, I prefer to loop over the original `list`, as no copies are needed. By the way, I am using a `numpy` array, but that doesn't really matter. the logic is what matters here. Thank you.

Comment: @user3262424: great! Which bit?

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  `do_stuff_with()` returning a tuple is a nice idea. I liked your post.

Comment: Instead of returning a tuple, it could raise an exception which you catch either inside or outside of your loop, as appropriate.

Comment: @xorsyst: That's a interesting idea. I didn't do this because I didn't consider this [flow exceptional](http://stackoverflow.com/a/77164/78845). Which of Python's `Exception`  classes would would you `raise`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I would create my own subclass of Exception for this, just to be sure I didn't catch anything I didn't want to.  You _could_ raise a StopIteration, which you wouldn't then need to catch I think, but it would have to be commented heavily!

Comment: @xorsyst: "but it would have to be commented heavily" certainly rings alarm bells. Have you read [Clean Code](http://tinyurl.com/CleanCodeBook)?

Comment: @Johnsyweb It should ring alarm bells! :)  But occasionally something unusual is the best approach, especially if you're optimizing for speed, which is ok providing you comment heavily about what it's doing and why.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to loop through all of it, then the cost of setting up a new generator (`xrange`) is quite small.

So the second approach would be faster, if you are sometimes skipping one or two of those loops.

That said, if your list is only 300 big, then the difference is going to be negligible, in the order of milliseconds or microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare speeds, just time them both:

```
import timeit

chunk1 = '''
sum = 0
for i in xrange(0, 300):
    sum += i
'''

chunk2 = '''
sum = 0
for i in xrange(0, 100):
    sum += i
for i in xrange(100, 200):
    sum += i
for i in xrange(200, 300):
    sum += i
'''

timer1 = timeit.Timer(chunk1)
timer2 = timeit.Timer(chunk2)

print timer1.timeit(100000)
print timer2.timeit(100000)
```

I get these numbers for `100,000` iterations:

```
3.44955992699
3.56597089767
```

As you can see, the second chunk of code is slightly slower.

---

You might be able to try a `while` loop and a `break` statement, so here's what I interpret you as trying to do:

```
i = 0

while i < limit:
  stop = False

  for j in xrange(i + 100, i + 300):
    if i == foo:
      stop = True
      break

  if stop:  break
  i += 1
```