# What to name a variant of a Get() method?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I am developing an API for a repository-like abstraction.  I have two methods:

```
// Throws an exception if object cannot be found
MyObj Get(MyIdType id);

// Returns false if object cannot be found; no exception
bool TryGet(out MyObj obj);
```

There is a requirement for a third variant: one that returns null if object cannot be found, and does not throw an exception.

```
// Returns null if object cannot be found; no exception
MyObj ?????(MyIdType id);
```

I'm stuck as on what to name it.  *GetOrDefault* has been ruled out as confusing.  *GetIfNotNull* has been suggested, but also seems unclear.  *GetOrNull* is the most promising so far.

Does anyone have any other suggestions, or know of any public APIs whose conventions I can follow?

Comment: Don't do it. Convince them that Get and TryGet are sufficient. Nulls are the devil.

Comment: I'd be more pissed that they want Get() to throw an exception if it's null. That's terrible.

Comment: @RickySmith it's not that the value exists and is null though, it's that a value doesn't exist with this key. In a `Dictionary` for example, this will throw an exception.

Comment: There are cases when it's ugly to use TryGet--lamba expressions become three lines instead of one.

Comment: I agree with you on that one @afeygin, however I don't think most will.

Comment: It really makes no sense to throw an exception

Comment: @ConnellWatkins .. I fail to see the difference. It's obviously not exceptional to ask for a key that doesn't exist. If it's not exceptional, then it's not appropriate as an exception. Exception handling is one of the most costly functions of programming.

Comment: @RickySmith it depends on the object really, Microsoft obviously think that trying to get a key that doesn't exist from most of their list based objects is exceptional. Probably because it's good practice to call `Contains` or `ContainsKey` first. There is actually barely any cost of a `try catch` statement, only when an exception is thrown.

Comment: And there is a difference between a key with no value and no key at all imo

Comment: @ConnellWatkins I'd be happy to debate all the points you've made, but  here is not the place. I apologize for bringing it up and detracting from the topic.

Comment: @RickySmith Pick up [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613) and read chapter 7: Exceptions. See what Microsoft's framework architects recommend. It's an eye-opener.

Answer (score 3):

I would opt to not have a Get method that behaves differently in two situations. Why not have the Get return null for all cases. Why throw an exception at all?

I would opt to leave it up to user code to throw an exception if a null value is returned, if required.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception) for further guidance related to when to throw exceptions.

Comment: exactly, why throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `GetOrDefault` (as you suggested yourself) based on the LINQ extension method `FirstOrDefault`.

Maybe `GetValue` and `GetValueOrDefault` would sound better though.

Comment: That was my original suggestion, but my clients ruled it out.

Comment: I hate clients... I'd convince them that those are the standard naming conventions used by Microsoft themselves (in LINQ). Pretty much all C# developers will know what this means without looking at a documentation, whereas any other method name you may need to document.

Comment: If the clients don't like your suggested method names, then I would suggest that the clients come up with their own method names.

Comment: @ConnellWatkins: unfortunately, without clients we don't have software to develop ;) - I do agree, though, that clients tend to make our jobs ...ummm ...challenging.

Comment: Indeed.. can't we all just develop for eachother? ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about: `GetOrDefault`

The `...OrDefault` is fairly standard in LINQ.

Comment: That was my original suggestion, but my clients ruled it out as too confusing because it could be interpreted as "defaulting" the object.

Comment: @afeygin - `GetValueOrNull` will be less ambiguous.

Comment: @afeygin it ***is*** defaulting the object

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should stick with:

```
MyObj Get(MyIdType id);
```

Instead of throwing an exception here, simply return `null`. **If** there is a definite requirement to throw an exception **or** optionally, `null`, I would try:

```
MyObj Get (MyIdType id, bool ReturnDefault = false) // if .net 4
```

I don't particularly like this option - but sometimes requirements will override what we think feels right or natural.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `GetObjectOrReturnDefaultValue` or, since you know it's a reference type `GetObjectOrReturnNull`.  It's long and ugly, but it's not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep only `bool TryGetXXXXX(out T value)` variant on your `interface` and provide the rest as extension methods to it. It makes your interface itself very compact, but at the same time as useful as client wants.