# C# - Exception logging and return status

Tags: c#, exception

Modifying to make it clear:

I have a question on exception logging and graceful exit. This is in continuation with previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831155/return-status-checking). The code looks like:

```
string status = "0";
ClassA ObjA = new ClassA();

try
{
    status = objA.Method1();
    if (status != "-1")
    {                        
        status = objA.Method1();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception Ex)
 {
     //Log Exception EX
 }
```

Inside the Method1:

```
public string Method1()
{
    string status = "0";
    try
    {
        //Code
        return "0";
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //Log Exception with details
        return "-1"
    }
}
```

I log the `Exception` in the calling method and return only a status to the caller. 
Should I return the `Exception` to the calling method or is only a status sufficient. With a status of "-1", I know there was an `Exception` in the called method and details of that `Exception` were logged in a log file.

Comment: "Best Practice": for what purpose?

Comment: Should i need to return exception to calling method or only status is sufficient. With -1 status i know exception in the called method and details of exception logged in log file.

Comment: Have you considered Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Nope i only checked in Stackoverflow right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `status` return value, it is not adding anything that is useful to you.

consider,

```
var a = new ClassA()
try
{
    a.Mehtod1();
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        a.Method1();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log without details;
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    void Method1()
    {
        try
        {
             //Code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log with details
            throw;
        }            
    }
}
```

This code achieves the same functionality but leaves the return code of the functions for something useful and non exceptional.

More generally, I suggest that you should have one catch all handler at the top level of your application that deals with logging, or at most one per public entry point. Other handlers should deal with specific exception types that they can actually "handle" (do something about.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is OK to do it like that if you have a lot of status codes, otherwise you could also just throw an exception and catch it in the method higher up.

Also maybe reconsider your return type. Looks like you could be using integers, think you are opening yourself up to errors using strings.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the purpose and implementation of the code; sometimes it is better to allow exceptions to pass back to the caller - they should be used in [exceptional cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception).

If you do intend on using return codes, however, I would be more inclined to use `enum`'s (though, again, it depends what the purpose of the code is). That way, it is easy for the caller to check against an available selection of return codes. Also, a comment on using integers or strings as error codes - it may not be very descriptive for a caller to know what the issue was. In this case, throwing an `Exception` or a specific type (containing the error message), or returning a pre-defined `enum` with a descriptive name, would be more meaningful to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

From these short code snippets which does nothing it is very difficult to say what is best practice.

In general it is best to push exceptions to where they are handled best. If you are writing a framework for interfacing with some webservice the users of your framework will most likely not care about network exceptions etc. - they want return codes or, even better some framework specific exceptions that you include/code.

Answer (score 1):

Hm - in your situation I'd rather do the following, but it really depends on the situation:

```
public string Method1()
{
    string status = "0";

    //Code - Exception may be thrown
    return "0";
}

string status = "0";
ClassA ObjA = new ClassA();
try
{
     status = objA.Method1();
 }
 Catch(Exception Ex)
 {
     //Log Exception EX
    status = "-1;
 }
```

**EDIT**
Sometimes it's hard to define values that indicate whether an error occurred in the method. You should keep `Nullable` types in mind. If you can find a suitable return value that indicates errors, it may also be ok to log the error within the method that caused the error and just react to the return value as you suggested.

By the way: In your code you're calling `Method1` twice if the first call succeeded. I guess that is because it is a quick sample...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is for invoking a service. Its for a Tool, But I would learn to make it more cleaner and better code.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyException : Exception
{
   public readonly int status;
   public  MyException(int status, string msg):base(msg)
   {
      this.status = status;
   }
}

public string Method1()
{   
   throw new MyException(-1,"msg");
    return "0";
}




SomeCode()
    {

         try
         {
                  Method1();
         }catch(MyException ex)
         { 
            ex.status //here you get the status
          }
     }
```