# What are the differences pre condition ,post condition and invariant in computer terminology

Tags: java, concurrency, uml, invariants

I am reading the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) and getting a little bit confused with these terms:

1. *Pre condition*
2. *Post condition*
3. *Invariants*

Can someone please explain me them (with an example, if it's possible)?

Comment: Also Assume when Unit Test and Given in BDD are examples of real world use of pre-conditions, and Assert & BDD Then clauses are examples of post-conditions.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You'll have a lot of problems writing Java, especially multi-threaded code, if you can't understand these simple ideas:

1. Pre-conditions are the things that must be true before a method is called.  The method tells clients "this is what I expect from you".
2. Post-conditions are the things that must be true after the method is complete.  The method tells clients "this is what I promise to do for you".
3. Invariants are the things that are always true and won't change.  The method tells clients "if this was true before you called me, I promise it'll still be true when I'm done".

They're all part of an idea called "programming by contract".  It was invented by a guy named [C.A.R. Hoare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic).  Bertrand Meyer built an object oriented language called [Eiffel](http://archive.eiffel.com/eiffel/nutshell.html) around it.  No one uses it much, but he had a day in the sun because of it.

Eiffel isn't very popular.  There are over four million questions on SO as I write this, but only 32 of them are tagged "eiffel".

Update: There were 11,966,392 question on SO on 29-Jun-2016.  Only 92 of them were tagged "eiffel".  The percentage of Eiffel questions is staying roughly constant at ~0.00077%.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic

Comment: So, when I'm writing a method with certain pre-conditions, would I check to see if those pre-conditions are satisfied, or am I to assume that the client is smart enough to not violate the pre-condition?

Comment: Your choice, but the whole idea is to validate and prevent errors. Ask yourself how consumers will know your contract.

Comment: I got here by reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/77127/845117 regarding 'When to throw an Exception'. The 3 Terms of Pre-, Postconditions and Invariants do sound clearly logic to me. And I would throw an Exception if any of these cannot be met by 'my' executing function. For me then, an Exception is a marker telling me execution did not terminate as expected/as declared - watch out!