# Exceptions: scope of use

Tags: exception

Can I use an exception as an easy way of jumping out of current context to some higher architecture layer to avoid routine return code checks (kinda `if ($response['code'] != CodeStatus::SUCCESS) return null;`)? The exceptions I talk about generally might mean something like invalid user account or smth, i.e it is not an emergency situation.

Comment: You may use knife to cut bread or to kill, just like with exceptions you can signal error or jump to arbitrary place upper in the call stack. I think you see analogy.

Comment: So the question is -- is it the exception's purpose? And can I actually use them in cases that are not emergencies? Isn't it akin a goto operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best answer I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception).

Also some [google research](https://www.google.ru/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=exceptions%20as%20control%20flow%20mechanism&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=OYR-UNngF-3S4QTo_oDADQ).