# How does this code works in java internal processing

Tags: java, exception

I know that finally block executes even if code throws exception or it completes successfully now my doubt is this code

> returns 40

which is obvious, but now if I

> comment return 40;
>
> it returns 10

can anybody help me understand how JVM returns 10 why it does not complain saying that function should return a value.

```
public class ExceptionTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=  returnSomething();
        System.out.println(i);
        }
    
        private static int returnSomething() {
            
            try{
                System.out.println("try");
                return 10;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return 20;
            }
            finally
            {
                System.out.println("finally ");
                return 40;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: You can have a look at this [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/188858). It might clear all your doubts!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616984/return-statement-in-java-exception-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java Language Specification,  [Section §14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing the try block. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S.
>
> ...
>
> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason
>     R, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for  reason R.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes bruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

When there is no `return` in the `try` block, then the `finally` block is executed and the `return` in the `finally` block will be used.

When there is a `return` in the `try` block, then it can be conscidered that the `try` block finished abruptly, however, according to the JLS, the `finally` block will still be executed before the code returns.

You can also refer to [Section §14.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) of the JLS to help understand the return statement.

Of interest, the note at the bottom of the section:

> The preceding descriptions say "attempts to transfer control" rather
>   than just "transfers control" because if there are any try statements
>   (§14.20) within the method or constructor whose try blocks or catch
>   clauses contain the return statement, then any finally clauses of
>   those try statements will be executed, in order, innermost to
>   outermost, before control is transferred to the invoker of the method
>   or constructor. Abrupt completion of a finally clause can disrupt the
>   transfer of control initiated by a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just before executing the `return` in the `try` block, the control gets transferred to the `finally` block.  Upon execution of the `finally` block, the function returns *unless* you have a `return` in the finally block itself.

As such, the function returns `40` when you have `return` in the finally block, and returns the value in the `try` block when you don't return in the finally block.

---

It is **not** recommended to return in the `finally` block.

Comment: A clean, short description.  Nearly perfect, (and it got my vote), but you might want to alter the wording "Upon reaching the ..." to "Just before executing the return in the try block...".  Upon reaching is just a touch vague in indicating whether it's just before executing, or during execution of.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Thanks.  Updated to get rid of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

`finally` block execute after `try` and `catch` block. So, if you comment `return 40` than it will return `try block` value if no exception occur. Thats why it `return 10`.

If exception occur than return `catch block` value of `20`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good read on the [finally block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

> > The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.