# Powershell logwrite and throw in same line

Tags: powershell

how would i write a log file, and do a throw in the same line ?

```
      Function LogWrite
    {
   Param ([string]$logstring)

 Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}
```

This works, but dont look so good in the code:

LogWrite "$ProgramName Not Installed"
throw "$ProgramName Not Installed"

Comment: Why does it need to be on the same line? Just put the `throw` after the `LogWrite` line.

Comment: In addition to @Rynant's comment, I would suggest that you read [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/77361/1324345) on SO about throwing exceptions in the first place. A return code may be more appropriate than a full-blown exception.

Comment: Thx, how would i add a timestamp in the logfile at every entry ? do you know that ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about repeating the `"$ProgramName Not Installed"` message, you could store the message in a variable and reuse it.

```
$msg = "$ProgramName Not Installed"
LogWrite $msg
throw $msg
```

Comment: Thx, how would i add a timestamp in the logfile at every entry ? do you know that ? :)

Comment: @Bendo1984 In your `LogWrite` function add something like `$logstring = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff ') + $logstring` before the `Add-Content` line. For formatting help see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thx alot works perfect - do you also think, that i should use exitcode instead of throw ?

Comment: @Bendo1984 I think it depends on what you are doing. But whenever I do use a `throw`, the `throw` is contained in a function that has the `[CmdLetBinding()]` attribute (run `help about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute` for explanation) that way an error can be ignored like: `Run-MyFunction 'test' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: But i dont want it to continue

Comment: Again, it depends on what you are doing, but if your script/function has the possibility of being called by other scripts/functions it is helpful to provide a clean way of handling the error (`-ErrorAction` can also take `Stop`, `Continue`, `Inquire` or `Ignore`). If you are going to throw an error that will never be caught, then why throw it? If that is the case, it would probably be better to `return` or `exit` from the script.