# Properly checking MySQLi OOP errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, string

I'm using OO MySQLi to work with a register form. I made the username column `unique` in my table and noticed that `$stmt` will throw an error when the code tries to use the `execute()` method, if a duplicate username is given.

I'd like to know how I can differentiate between other errors and a duplicate username error in the error detection? At the moment I'm essentially doing this:

```
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->error)
    die();
```

The problem is that if `execute()` fails for another reason (instead of duplicate username), I'll most likely want to log it, but I don't want to log everytime a user tries to register with a taken username. The simplest (and probably not a very good) solution I came up with right away was to analyze the `$stmt->error` message. If the problem is about duplicate usernames, the string will be `"Duplicate entry 'value' for key 'column'"`, so I could just check if the strings first words are `"Duplicate entry "`. But I guess that'd be prone to errors.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`mysql_statement`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.sqlstate.php) has a `$sqlstate` property, taking values documented [in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html).

If you work with exceptions, [`mysqli_sql_exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) also has two extra relevant properties:

```
protected string $sqlstate ;
protected int $code ;
```

You want to check that `error = 1062` or `sqlstate = '23000'`.

Comment: As suggested by [Pez Cuckow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25160307/1446005) and [Hammerstein](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160267/properly-checking-mysqli-oop-errors#comment39169947_25160307]), I wouldn't rely on exceptions for this use case. Exceptions should be reserved to exceptional cases that you knowingly decide not to handle yourself. (see also: [When to throw an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/77127/1446005))

Answer (score 0):

You could run a statement before the insert to check if the username already exists in the table and if it doesn't then run the insert statement, else log it/throw errors as needed.

Comment: I'd rather not run a statement for such a small thing. I'll do that if nothing else works, because it seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you noticed any such impact, especially if the username column is indexed.

Comment: Why is it a waste of resources to make check if a username exists? Relying on the exception is probably a bigger waste of resources.

Comment: @Hammerstein any kind of source to back that claim up?