# Should I return a status code or throw an exception in .Net Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

I have seen examples like [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return Ok(item);
}
```

But I have also imagine this is an option

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(item);
}
```

Is there an advantage to throwing an exception or simply returning a NotFound (IHttpActionResult instance)?

I know there are stages in the response / request pipeline where either of these results can be handled, like this for the first example

```
public class NotFoundExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotFoundException)
        {
            // Do some custom stuff here ...
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
}

...

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(
    new ProductStore.NotFoundExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IHttpActionResult` is a feature that was added in WebApi 2.  The traditional methods from WebApi 1, i.e. creating an `HttpResponseMessage` or throwing an `HttpResponseException`, are still available to you, but the `IHttpActionResult` was developed to streamline the process.

The `IHttpActionResult` Interface has one method:

```
public interface IHttpActionResult
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

The [`NotFound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.notfound.aspx) method simply creates a [`NotFoundResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.notfoundresult.aspx) which returns an empty response with `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.  This is essentially the exact same thing that throwing `HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)` does, but in a more uniform syntax.

The `IHttpActionResult` interface also allows you to easily create custom `ActionResult` classes to return any `HttpStatusCode` or any content type you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception is always should be considered as an **exceptional** case. While being rare, it still can happen and should be handled properly.

It depends on how often do you need to retrieve nonexistent items from your database. Keep in mind that often exception throwing is **always** a performance killer.

You should also look into this:

> [When to throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception)

Comment: While that is true for normal desktop/app programming, I think WebAPI uses exceptions a little differently so I don't know if this advice is as valid as it normally is.