# How do i throw an exception and also execute the remaining business logic in the catch block?

Tags: java

I want a hack here. What I am trying out is to execute some of the business logic after throwing an exception. The business logic is defined in the catch block. I don't want to keep the throw statement at the end of the catch block. Is there any hack I can try? What I am thinking is to create a thread in that point and inside that throw the exception. I am not sure whether it will work or not. Please help me out.

```
package demo1.web;

import demo.exceptions.SupportInfoException;

public class TestInnerException {
void testIt() throws Exception{
    try{
        int i=0;
        int j=1/i;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("business logic .. .. . . ");
        throw e;
        // I want to excute these below line ,
         but it is unreachable because you aleready throwing the excetion ..
        //any Hacks for it ?
         System.out.println("Lines after throwing the exception ... .");

    }

    System.out.println("I want this logic to be run . . . . .");

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws SupportInfoException, Exception {
    TestInnerException t = new TestInnerException();
    t.testIt();


}
void testRunTimeEx(){
        int i=0;
        int j=1/i;

}
}
```

Let me tell you my scenario , I am having @ExceptionHandler annotation to handle all the exception as described in this post . https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#user-content-sample-application   Some complex scenario , cant explain why exactly . What i want here is if it is handled by catch block then i want that to be triggered in @ExceptionHandler because there i have some other Business logic . The problem is @ExceptionHandler is not triggered unless exception is thrown.  I want that to be triggered if it entered the catch block.  But Its not triggered if the catch block doesnt throw any exception.

Business logic in this context I mean as some Logging Function.

Comment: I simply don't understand why anyone would want to do that?. If you want to execute those lines, then don't throw exception there

Comment: You should not have any business login in exception handlers / catch / finally blocks. On resource cleanup

Comment: Rethink your design. `An exception is thrown when a fundamental assumption of the current code block is found to be false`. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception). You should NOT be able to continue after you've thrown an exception.

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar Exactly. Looks like a design smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just not hack, perhaps won't make much sense.

1) If you want to `throw` some exception, `throw` right away.

2) If you want to do some business logic on `exception` raise, do it and then `throw` the `exception`.

But if you want to throw and do some, not quite possible without any dirty code here. Seems a code smell here to me.

Edit after the [question Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32307256/revisions) :

Though it is logging, still you can log before throwing it, there is no point to generate log after throwing it.