# Should an exception be thrown or should the method simply return?

Tags: c#, exception, preconditions

I am currently wondering about what is "best" to do if `null` is passed to the following method. Should it silently return (as it does no) or should it throw an exception instead?

```cs
public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if(propertyName is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}
```

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361/7571171) it says

> [I]f the function's assumptions about its inputs are violated, it should throw an exception instead of returning normally

and I believe the function *assumes* that a non-`null` input is passed to it, however, it could still execute (successfully?) as it simply does nothing if `null` is passed.

---

Is throwing an exception instead of returning the "best" thing to do here in terms of good / clean code?

Comment: Is it *exceptional* that its `null` (or white space)? if it is, throw. if its not exceptional, then deal with it in another way. The only rule here is don't use exceptions for *flow control*.

Comment: I'd argue like this: If the parameter here is `null` it seems to be a programming error that should be made aware of early on (during development / testing). So, I'd do one of two things: a) add a `Debug.Assert` or b) throw an `ArgumentNullException`. If the premise does not hold (coding error if `null`) then this argument is invalid, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a missing property name is considered to be a development error, then the method should throw an `ArgumentNullException`. Otherwise, it's fine to silently return.

Whatever you do, a bit safer would be to test for `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName)`. When you do this, just throw an `ArgumentException` when a proper name is not provided.